# Securely Wipe/Shred Files in Pantheon via Right Click menu

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, pantheon

Is there a way to add shred to ElementaryOS content menu? So instead of typing `shred -f -v -z -u file.zip` I can just right click the file and delete it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be possible with a contractor, something like this:

`[Contractor Entry]
Name=Shred
Description=Securely delete a file
Icon=
MimeType=!inode/blockdevice;inode/chardevice;inode/fifo;inode/socket;
Exec=shred -f -z -u %f`

Place this in `/usr/share/contractor/shred.contract` and you should then get an entry when you right-click on a file.